# Bandwidth distance product

Tags: bandwidth, distance, capacity

A fundamental principle of communications states that for any given transmission medium, bandwidth-length product is constant. I know that optical fibers, for example, are used for high data rate transmission over long distances. High data rates means high bandwidth and high carrier frequency. According to the constant bandwidth distance constant principle, we can decrease the carrier frequencies used with optical fibers, and thus increase the transmission distance. My question is: can we use very low frequencies (in the range of kilohertz) with optical fibers to transmit data over very large distances? Of course the bit rate will be very low, but I am asking about the possibility to transmit very low frequencies over optical fibers.

Comment: "*we can decrease the carrier frequencies used with optical fibers, and thus increase the transmission distance.*" This might be a tendency but is not a rule. I'm a bit suspicious this tendency even applies to fiber optics. It sort of applies to radio waves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we use very low frequencies (in the range of kilohertz) with optical fibers to transmit data over very large distances?

Can we launch a 100 kHz electromagnetic wave into an optical fiber?

No, 100 kHz is below the cut-off frequency of the fiber, and won't be guided by the fiber structure.

Can we modulate the optical (100-200 THz) carrier with a 100 kHz data signal and achieve a very long link distance?

Yes. As the modulation bandwidth around the carrier is reduced, the achievable link distance is increased, maintaining a (nearly) constant bandwidth-distance product.

At very low modulation frequencies, unfortunately, the link distance will be limited by loss effects rather than the dispersion effects that determine the bandwidth-distance product at normal data rates. So you can't extend the link distance to infinity just by reducing the data rate to nearly 0.

Comment: To what range of bandwidth and distance this principle is applicable?

Comment: To which extent can the bandwidth of optical fiber be decreased, and thus to what range can the distance be increased?

Comment: @Noha Wouldn't an answer to your question depend upon the specific materials and implementation and no longer be a theoretical question, but one of the current state of knowledge about materials and construction and the ambient environmental circumstances?

Comment: @Noha Completely dependent on the material. 100kHz is no longer "optical". It's radio. If you have a material that guide radio waves then you can make a radio fiber. If you don't have such a material, then you can't. And range may not necessarily increase either. Depends on the attenuation of the material.

Comment: @Noha, sorry I don't know. In 20 years working in fiber optics, nobody's ever asked me,  "how slow a system can you design? "

Comment: @ The Photon Of course I am not asking about designing a slow system. I read the following in one reference: A copper wire (twisted pair), the link traditionally associated with low bit rate transmission, is still in use in the modern data centers transmitting data at 20 Gbit/sec. The secret? it does so only over a few meters (the bandwidth distance product is constant). Here, the system is much faster. I am wondering how the copper wire could support this very wide bandwidth. Thus, my question in general, is what limits the application of the bandwidth distance product rule?

Answer (score -1):

Bandwidth in fiber optic channels is rarely limited by the capacity of the channel itself (which is unimaginably large for something like smf28), so the bandwidth length product is essentially meaningless. The bandwidth of the channel is whatever you're willing to pay for, which at present is usually very little compared to physical limits imposed by attenuation, nonlinearity and Shannon's limit.

As for range, there are plans for laser communications to other planets. Distances on Earth are small enough that you don't even need to lower the bandwidth, at least if you've got the budget.